# Format StreamWriter to Write/Append Json in Valid format

Tags: c#, json

Good day,

How can i save/append JSON data in to the File with StreamWriter in a valid JSON format ? Is there a way to Format StreamWriter to append/write file in valid JSON format?

Like :

```
    `[
         { "data1": "data1" },
         { "appended data2": "appended data2" },
         { "appended data3": "appended data3" },
     ]`
```

I'm using NewtonJson to serialize JSON from an object and then save it with StreamWriter.

```
WritableData an_data = new WritableData
{
     Titel = tbTitel.Text,
     Type = tbType.Text,
     Episode = tbEps.Text,
     Score = tbScore.Text,
     Id = tbID.Text,
     TitleEng = tbTitelEng.Text,
     Status = tbStatus.Text,
     StartDate = tbDateStart.Text,
     EndDate = tbDateEnd.Text,
     Image = pbImage.ImageLocation
};

string path = SavePath + "\\AnList";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(an_data, Formatting.Indented);

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + listFile, true);
tw.WriteLine(json);
tw.Close();
```

And it is being save as follows :

`{
  "Titel": "Test1",
  "Type": "Movie",
  "Episode": "1",
  "Score": "6.92",
  "Id": "894",
  "TitleEng": "Test1",
  "Status": "Finished Airing",
  "StartDate": "1989-07-15",
  "EndDate": "1989-07-15",
  "Image": "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/5/10193.jpg"
}{
  "Titel": "Test2",
  "Type": "TV",
  "Episode": "153",
  "Score": "8.16",
  "Id": "223",
  "TitleEng": "Test2",
  "Status": "Finished Airing",
  "StartDate": "1986-02-26",
  "EndDate": "1989-04-12",
  "Image": "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/9/21055.jpg"
}`

I couldn't find a way to format it right.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Use JObject and add a property you want the write the whole file

Comment: @Jamiec i have edited the code , with data that `an_data` contains

Comment: @FilipCordas i thought that it would be the best way to save Object as JSON. I'm new to c# and programming , so if there is a better way i will use it

Comment: @Jamiec sorry for that, have posted exactly as it is in the file.

Comment: I still think its rubbish - there are supposedly 2 results in your file, but only 1 object being created. Once again read this link [mcve]. In any case, it IS the right format - the output format is exactly (for each object) the correct format for JSON. If you want an array written out, you need to pass an array/list in

Comment: @Jamiec Oooh so the `[ ]` in Json means that it is an array. And i actualy have correct format. Now i get it. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You save your data to the file by appending text to the end. From what magic there'll be `[` in the beginning and `]` in the end? :)

Why don't you just create an array/list of objects you want to save to the file then serialize it as a whole and save text to the file?

```
var list = new List<WritableData>();
list.Add(an_data1);
list.Add(an_data2);
//...
list.Add(an_dataN);

var serialized = JsonConverter.SerializeObject(list);
// write to the file with 'overwrite' option, i.e. new StreamWriter(path, false/*!!!*/)
```

Or another approach is appending text one-by-one like you tried to do. It'll require some tricks:

- create text file as `[]`,
- then every time you want to save your object (of the same type as the other previous objects), you need to:

  - open file and remove the last symbol `]`,
  - append `,`,
  - append serialized object as you do in your example,
  - append `]`

So every time you'll have a valid json of this, looked like this:

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
    {...}
]
```

Comment: This is what i have meant, i guess i'm a bad with asking  proper questions. Now i get it. Thank you !!

Answer (score -2):

You want to add more properties to your `an_data`?  So add more properties to the class.

```
var an_data = new WritableData() { //btw, use camelCase in var names
    Prop1 = "foo",
    Prop2 = "bar"
};
```

Or use a dictionary:

```
var an_data = new WritableData() {
    AppendableData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
}
an_data.AppendableData["foo"] = "bar";
an_data.AppendableData["bar"] = "foo";
```

Comment: This isn't what i want but it is also helpfull and will help me in the future, thank you !! Preatty much the answer were answered by @pkuderov.

Answer (score -3):

Ideally the serialized class (WriteableData) should contain all fields to be (de)serialized. If it doesn't and you manually append some json data then you won't be able to deserialize that appended data. If you really need to work around this and don't know what data the Json object may contain then consider using Dictionary to store some of that unknown data. But I'd advise to strongly type your serializable json object class. Otherwise you're just inviting hard to maintain code.